# Add 'slider' function to jQuery cycle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-cycle

Using jQuery's cycle plugin for a basic slide (using fade) banner.
I'd like to have an image move right every time it slides, to show what image we're on.
The way I've coded it, it works once and then stops. I'd like to have it slide ride each time the image changes and then have it slide back to the first image at the end.
I've create the following Fiddle to show what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/9QXWn/
It does it once, and then stops.
Could someone modify the JSFiddle to have it change each time? And if it's not too much to ask, have it reset when it's processed the queue once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO you can put your function in the `before` or `after` parameter of cycle method.
please check this http://jsfiddle.net/bondythegreat/HPwca/1/

Comment: and how to bring it back to the first position (reset), simply put an IFclause in your function that is fired when it reach the end of the loop (or it back to the first image)

Comment: Thanks! :) And to make the text slide when the image changes instead of before/after, I added a timeout to it. Not sure if that's the best way but it works! :)